# Magento,how restrict admin users to edit/view order at the same time?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to be able to restrict the access of admin users to edit a sales order(Sales->Orders->View) when is already being edited. Similar how wordpress handles it when editing a post. is there a way to achieve this functionality within magento?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a programming-related Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Answer (score 1):

For that create a new role without view permission and assign it to a user.

**Options**

System->Permissions->Roles

System->Permissions->Users

[image]